# Spring Security OAuth 2: How to use access token in the javascript client

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-oauth2

I have three applications: REST API with Resource Server, Authorization Server and javascript client on VueJs that should use REST Api. Problem in using access token that I get after authorization. First I decided to use local storage or cookie for storing access token, but as I read It's not secure. It's recommended to use cookie with httpOnly, but I can't to access from js. Addition token in url params as well not right way. So what I should to do for using my Rest Api? I'm using Authorization Code grant flow.

Comment: Why not doing it on backend side? You can write a client and store it in your server. Try this: https://github.com/scribejava/scribejava

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a Javascript client, the client itself should act as an *OAuth2 client*.

Meaning, the server is not what gets the token. The client, the javascript application in the browser, will fetch the token from the authorization server.

You achieve this by using a grant type called [`implicit`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.2).

In this grant type, there is no client_secret, but you must have a valid client_id. You will also not receive a refresh token. But you can receive access tokens and id_token (if you have an OIDC server).

Your question hints at you doing a server side grant (authorization_code,password,etc) and then sending that token to the javascript client. This would be incorrect.

For a great description of OAuth2, we have published this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u4BHKcZ2rxk

Your JavaScript application would do this:

1. Do I have a valid token? No
2. Start implicit grant
3. Receive token from authorization server
4. Store token in memory `var token = ....`
5. Use the token to invoke API endpoints on the server
6. Repeat step 5 until token is no longer valid
7. Go back to step 1

Next step for you is to watch the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u4BHKcZ2rxk) and learn more about [implicit grant type](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/05/24/what-is-the-oauth2-implicit-grant-type)

As you already guessed, going down the road of getting a token on the server and then sending it to a non secure client exposes your applications in ways you probably do not want.

Comment: You’re welcome. There are Jacascript frameworks that do all this for you.

Comment: I am going to update this answer to also include OpenId Connect Session, if that’s relevant. I have to refresh my memory on it.

Comment: Good day! Do you have an updated information in regards with the links you have posted here? Majority of the link you used are now gone. Thank you!